# How to show google map without internet in ios

Tags: javascript, iphone

I am showing google map using javascript in a html file,can i show that map when internet connection is not there,is there any jquery api for that, any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

above code is in html file and i am loading this html file in webview

Answer (score 0):

**No** You can't.Now for offline maps you have two options in my opinion

use [arcGIS server](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis) and establish its server to get offline and online maps( *But in case of use this , you need a arcGIS expert or you need to study about this* ).arcGIS publish its services and you just need to call/display/read that service.So it would be a comfortable support for you if you [establish arcGIS](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis).
The second options is to store images manually in DB and display them on events(Javascript/jquery).For this you have to store all images in DB which you will display in your system/product.
You can find alot of API's regarding this
see [mapper.js](http://www.netzgesta.de/mapper/) 
[imagemapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/) is also awesome 
as well as you can find [jquery plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/maphilight) whose [demo](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html) is here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169478/displaying-mkmapview-without-internet-access

Comment: if i will use mkmapkit and i open map when i was  on-line and load the india map, then i close  the app, and disconnect net and restart the app then i will be able to look at india again, but if i try to go to france i don't see it...like that i want to do.

Comment: have you seen the question? It is according to your requirement after then implement it as I answered you